# Asp Net Dynamic Data apply filter foreign key value in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have a GridView that use DynamicField. When the gridivew set to edit mode i show in foreign key column the dropdwonlist of related tables. In this case i have to filter record by database column. How can I do that? I need to don't show all record of related foreign key table but filtered data!

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom fieldTemplate and use UIHintAttribute to override the default.